# Insert Customer Location from an action

Tags: acumatica

I have an action where a new customer location is created.
So far, I'm just trying to load the page with an existing record.

With this code, the result is positive

> ```
>     public virtual IEnumerable NewLocation(PXAdapter adapter)
>     {
>             CustomerLocationMaint locationGraph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<CustomerLocationMaint>();
>             Location locationRow = new Location();
>             locationGraph.Location.Current = locationGraph.Location.Search<Location.locationID>(116, "ABARTENDE");
>             locationGraph.Location.Insert(locationRow);
>             throw new PXRedirectRequiredException(locationGraph, null) { Mode = PXBaseRedirectException.WindowMode.NewWindow };
>                     return adapter.Get();
>     }
> ```

However, this other version loads the page blank:

> ```
>     public virtual IEnumerable NewLocation(PXAdapter adapter)
>     {
>             CustomerLocationMaint locationGraph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<CustomerLocationMaint>();
>             Location locationRow = new Location();
>             locationRow.BAccountID = 109; //ABARTENDE
>             locationRow.LocationID = 116; //MAIN
>             locationGraph.Location.Insert(locationRow);
>             throw new PXRedirectRequiredException(locationGraph, null) { Mode = PXBaseRedirectException.WindowMode.NewWindow };
>                     return adapter.Get();
>     }
> ```

I need to have a version similar to the second one, because eventually, the new LocationCD will be entered from this action.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the second example, you're trying to set the LocationID explicitly, this is an identity field that needs to be assigned.  I found a couple of examples in the source:

```
    public PXDBAction<BAccount> addLocation;
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = Messages.AddNewLocation)]
    [PXButton(ImageKey = PX.Web.UI.Sprite.Main.DataEntry)]
    public virtual void AddLocation()
    {
        var row = BAccount.Current;
        if (row == null || row.BAccountID == null) return;

        LocationMaint graph = null;
        switch (row.Type)
        {
            case BAccountType.VendorType:
                graph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<AP.VendorLocationMaint>();
                break;
            case BAccountType.CustomerType:
                graph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<AR.CustomerLocationMaint>();
                break;
            default:
                graph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<LocationMaint>();
                break;
        }


        var newLocation = (Location)graph.Location.Cache.CreateInstance();
        newLocation.BAccountID = row.BAccountID;
        var locType = LocTypeList.CustomerLoc;
        switch (row.Type)
        {
            case BAccountType.VendorType:
                locType = LocTypeList.VendorLoc;
                break;
            case BAccountType.CombinedType:
                locType = LocTypeList.CombinedLoc;
                break;
        }
        newLocation.LocType = locType;
        graph.Location.Insert(newLocation);
        PXRedirectHelper.TryRedirect(graph, PXRedirectHelper.WindowMode.NewWindow);

    }
```